# In Maschke's theorem, does the averaged projector $\bar P_U$ equal $P_U$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

Consider a finite group $G$ represented on a $\mathbb K$-vector space $V$ with $\operatorname{char}\mathbb K$ not dividing $|G|$, and let $U$ be an invariant subspace for the representation, and $W$ another subspace such that $V=U\oplus W$.

Then, to prove that $W$ is also an invariant, given the projector $P_U$ onto the invariant $U$ we define the averaged projector $\bar P_U$ as
$$\bar P_U = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g^{-1}P_U g.$$
This can be shown to be an intertwiner for the representation, $\bar P_U g=g \bar P_U$ for all $g\in G$, *and* a projector itself, $\bar P_U^2=\bar P_U$.

While I think I understand while this is the case, I'm not quite clear on the relation between $P_U$ and $\bar P_U$. They clearly agree on $U$: $P_U u=\bar P_U u=u$ for all $u\in U$, and they are both projectors. Doesn't this imply that $P_U=\bar P_U$?

I say this because if $P$ and $Q$ are projectors defined on the same vector space with the same image, then $(P-Q)x=0$ both for $x\in\operatorname{im}(P)=\operatorname{im}(Q)$ and for $x\in\ker P=\ker Q$, and thus $P=Q$.

If this is so, shouldn't there be a more direct way to prove the theorem working directly with $P_U$?

Comment: No, $P_U$ and $\bar{P}_U$ are not equal. Projectors can be distinct and yet have the same image. (Think of a plane and a line: You can project onto that line under different angles.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't quite get what you mean, sorry. I guess my argument was assuming *orthogonal* projectors, as otherwise $\ker P\perp\operatorname{im}P$ doesn't hold, but if $P,Q$ are orthogonal projectors and they have the same image, it is true that $P=Q$, correct? Then this means that $P_U$ and $\bar P_U$  are not both orthogonal? Is there a direct way to see this?

Comment: Yep, "projection" does not mean "orthogonal projection". And $\bar{P}_U$ will usually not be orthogonal (even if $P_U$ was!), unless your inner product is $G$-invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see this is via examples.

First of all, as darij grinberg pointed out in the comments, two projectors with the same image need not agree : take the plane $k^2$, there is one projector onto $k\times \{0\}$ with kernel $\{0\}\times k$, and one with kernel $k (1,1)$ for instance.

Note that over an arbitrary field, the notion of "orthogonal" projector might not make sense (and even over $\mathbb {R,C}$, if you did not specifiy the scalar product on your vector space, it doesn't make sense)

So for instance take the action of $\mathfrak S_2$ on $k^2$ that simply permutes the coordinates. An obvious invariant subspace is $U=k(1,1)$. Indeed its elements are of the form $(\lambda, \lambda)$, so if you permute the coordinates, you don't move. Now, a possible projector might be $p$ with kernel $k\times \{0\}$, indeed $k\times \{0\}\oplus k(1,1) = k^2$.

Explicitly, you have $p(x,y) = (y,y)$. This is clearly not $\mathfrak S_2$-invariant : $p(\sigma(\lambda, \mu)) = p(\mu,\lambda) = (\lambda, \lambda) \neq (\mu,\mu) = \sigma (\mu, \mu) = \sigma p(\lambda, \mu)$, if $\lambda\neq \mu$ where $\sigma\in \mathfrak S_2$ is the transposition.

Now if you average $p$ over $\mathfrak S_2$, you get $q= \frac{1}{2}(p + \sigma p \sigma)$ so $q(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}((y,y) + (x,x))= \frac{1}{2}(x+y,x+y)$.

Its kernel is now $k(1,-1)$ , which is now clearly an invariant subspace (its elements are of the form $(\lambda, -\lambda)$, so if you permute the coordinates you get $(-\lambda, -(-\lambda))$, which is still in the space)

This is the simplest example, but of course you can always find examples.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know of an example in which the averaged projector $\bar P$ turns out to not be orthogonal instead?

Comment: Well again, in general it doesn't make sense to ask whether a projector is orthogonal. But of course there are examples, as soon as you don't act via isometries. For instance if you take the same action as the one I gave, with $k=\mathbb R$, but change the scalar product to $(x \mid y) := 2x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$, everything stays the same but $((1,1) \mid (1,-1) ) = 2 - 1 = 1\neq 0$ so the projector isn't orthogonal. Up to a change of basis, this means we have the usual scalar product, but $\sigma$ now acts as $\sigma (x,y) = (\sqrt{2}y, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x)$